# Fatal error: qapplication.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, qt

When I try to run my first program in QT I get the followinging error:

> /untitled1/main.cpp:1:26: fatal error: qapplication.h: No such file or
>   directory  #include 
>                             ^ compilation terminated. make: *** [main.o] Error 1 09:38:51: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
>   Error while building/deploying project untitled1 (kit: Desktop) When
>   executing step 'Make' 09:38:52: Elapsed time: 00:01.

Please help me.

Comment: Try including `QT += widgets` in your .pro file.

Comment: where i found .pro in my system?

Comment: It should be in the same directory as your source files. Also replace `qapplication.h` with `<QApplication>`

Comment: i add these line in vashu.pro   but still same error

Comment: that file contain these info

TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += main.cpp

Comment: You are not *running* your program, you are trying to *compile* it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Install Qt Creator from the Ubuntu Software Center (I know from reading your other question that you are using Ubuntu).
2. Visit the [Qt for beginners — Hello World!](https://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt_for_beginners_Hello_World) tutorial website.
3. Follow the steps in the Qt for beginners — Hello World! tutorial.
   **Tip:** Make a new folder in your /home directory for your Qt Projects before you start the tutorial. Call the new folder *QtProjects* or whatever name you like.
4. The output of the tutorial Hello World! application will appear in a separate popup window after you compile and run it.

Comment: i already install Qt creator and QT sdk but i have no idea about version?

Comment: You don't need to know the Qt version if you include the line that says `greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets` in your project file like the tutorial says. Then in Qt Creator, it will select the correct Qt version for you automatically. You also don't need to know the Qt version when you create a new project in Qt Creator, just accept the defaults.

Comment: Some background information: I have two Open Documents in my Qt Creator window: main.cpp and HelloWorld.pro (my project file). I use *Build* -> *Build All* from the Qt Creator menu to build and then use the green run arrow in the lower left corner of the GUI to run the application.